mat-list-option deselecting itself when recreated in virtual-scroll-viewport
I have a wrapper component for the mat-selection-list to support generic filtering. Also I have a master checkbox to select everything in the current filter scope. To support large datasets I also have an option for virtual scrolling using the experimental autosize-directive.
Since I allow filtering the source set of the list is constantly changing which clears the selection if an option is filtered out. To prevent this, I use the angular SelectionModel and the callbacks of the mat-list-options. But here is the problem:
Since the options are destroyed and recreated while scrolling through the viewport, the selectedChange event of the option is triggered with the initial unselected state of an option, so an option deselects itself when being recreated. But since this does not happen all the time, it seems there is a race between (selectedChange) and [selected].
Here is the reproducible example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-iidbcx
